# W3C compliant HTMl and CSS

Tags: php, html, css, validation, w3c

I have PHP app which a HTML and CSS files which I submit (can't say more) and they must use **W3C compliant HTML5 and CSS**.

The input number is POSTed to PHP and a Multiplication Table is generated. CSS is only applied to the generated table. The `index.php` and `styles.css` files are as follow:

```css
table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.heading {
    font-weight: 700;
}
td {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Multilplication Table</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

<form action="MultiplicationTableHTML.php" method="POST">

    Please Enter a Number:

    <input type="number" min="1" name="number" placeholder="Enter a number">

    <button type="submit">Generate</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Either one of both of these files give

> 3 Validation error

The error have to do with W3C standards and even after lots of researching and using many online tools, I can't seem to fix the error.

Any questions, feel free to ask and any suggested are much appreciated.

Comment: missing a label maybe?

Comment: I'll give it a try but still doesn't explain the 3 errors.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the errors are. It's all a bit mysterious otherwise!

Comment: @WebGuy I have to say that the W3C validators are quite weird. I mean they don't allow for browser prefixed CSS which should be valid but according to W3C isn't

Comment: @WebGuy I can think of 2 it might flag (1) input without label (2) form has no label element? not sure though

Comment: I put that html code into https://validator.w3.org/ and it says it's perfect

Comment: Same for the css (no errors).

Comment: @Utkanos Unfortunately, errors are not given and for me to find and fix.

Comment: I'll try the label and see if it works and post any progress that I might make. Thanks for the suggestions guys :)

Comment: *I have PHP app which a HTML and CSS files which I submit*. Sorry, what? I don't understand this. And what is a Multiplication Table in this context? And who or what says there's an error, and what error? This is all very vague.

Comment: @WebGuy - that makes no sense; a HTML/CSS validator *does* tell you what the errors are. They'd be pretty useless if they told you merely that there were errors, but not what they were.

Comment: Okay, I will update the questions today and include some more information, but I think I know where the issue is and I sincerely thank everyone for taking trying to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I apologise if I couldn't provide enough details on the problem but as I later found out there were no problems with the code above but instead, I was simply outputting an HTML table within PHP without proper HTML structure on another page (e.g. without the head, body and meta tags). Hence, problem solved.

Thanks again to everyone who gave their suggestions.

Git Repo if anyone is interested: https://github.com/ByWaleed/PHP-Multiplication-Table